# Reload Adsense ads, or have to use DFP?

Tags: javascript, reload, ads, adsense, google-dfp

I've found a number of sites that explain how to make a DFP ad reload/refresh after 30-120 seconds, but none of them explain if it's possible to do with an Adsense ad.

I've tried DFP - it's very confusing compared to Adsense.

My current Adsense code:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- MYSITE- Responsive - #1 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-123456789..."
     data-ad-slot="123456789"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AdSense's [TOS](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms) disallow the sort of automatic refreshing you're referring to. This does not mean that you *cannot* automatically refresh AdSense Tags programmatically. It does mean that you will almost certainly get banned for doing so.

On the other hand, this behavior is allowed when using AdSense + Doubleclick for publishers (DFP). [This documentation](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3058726?hl=en) should point you in the right direction, and you'd want to call something like this to refresh your ads:

`googletag.pubads().refresh();`

The following tutorials should  give you enough information to figure out how to use AdSense + DFP:

1. [General Tutorial #1](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-dfp-tutorial/14099/) (Outdated, but still useful)
2. [General Tutorial #2](http://www.dfptutorial.com/) (Also outdated, but useful nonetheless)
3. [Linking AdSense + DFP](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/188529?hl=en) (This doesn't work if you're using DFP for Small Business; instead, you'll just want to add you Adsense embed code as a third-party creative

If you are adamant about automatically refreshing ads without DFP, you could do the following wrapped in a timer function:

`document.getElementById('FrameID').contentWindow.location.reload(true);`

Be advised: **This will get you banned from AdSense if you are not using the service through DFP**

Comment: So you aren't allowed ("can't") do it with just Adsense, but you can if you use Adsense through DFP?

Comment: @Dave see my clarifications above, and good luck. Setting up AdSense + DFP with automatic refreshes isn't a terribly simple process.

Comment: Cool thanks for the details!  I do want to be "legit", so I guess I'll have to suck it up and get used to DFP.  Appreciate the answer and details.

Comment: It's not clear, but maybe AdSense autorefresh is allowed as long it's user initiated. See: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295#Auto-refreshing_ads . It says: "Publishers are not permitted to refresh a page or an element of a page without the user requesting a refresh." So if user interacts with website, is ad refresh allowed?

Comment: @szymond did you figure that out? I need to refresh the ad, when a user clicks on next, even though I'm not refreshing the site, just the content. I think that would be what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after the start `<head>` tag

```
<script async src=”//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js”></script>
<script src=’http://connect.kyowal.com/kp_dev/developer/refresh.js’ type=’text/javascript’/>
<script>
var adsenceblockone = ‘<ins class=’adsbygoogle’ data-ad-client=’ca-pub-1385863686986530′ data-ad-format=’auto’ data-ad-slot=’5134528809′ style=’display:block’/>‘;
</script>
```

Place this code where you want to show your ads on page

```
<div id=”adsrefreshone”></div>
<script>
adsencerefreshone();
</script>
```

This code will work only for one advertisement

if you like to show more ads Read the full post here
http://www.kyowal.com/rsiwal/posts/8702